# G-code (M-code?) for Get Bed Temperature

Tags: heated-bed, g-code

I'm familiar with 3D printing, and the G-code concept. I'm also comfortable with programming.

Can anyone give me the G-code (or probably the M-code, actually) to read the bed temperature?

Is there an equivalent of `M105` (Get Extruder Temperature)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`M105` should give you the bed temperature.

For future reference you can find a general list of G/M codes here - [RepRap Wiki - G-code](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code).

Most firmware files include a list, Marlin has it in [Marlin_main](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp).  I have no idea how often the list is updated but they don't change often.

Comment: M105 is the extruder temperature. I can''t find a way to get the bed temperature, though there is a code to wait until the bed has reached the target temperature.

Comment: @NomadMaker M105 should report the temperature for everything.

Comment: @NomadMaker please look into http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M105.html

Comment: Your Marlin_main link had died, so I changed it